# foreach loop is giving incorrect result

Tags: php

I'm trying to use foreach loop for an array. When I print_r the array it gives me following:

```
Array ( [ID] => 1 [Value] => NYC125 [User] => 1 [Uses] => 1 [Amount] => 10 [End] => 1574467200 )
```

But when I'm trying to use foreach it gives me this kind of strange thing:

```
1
1
N
N
N
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

My foreach code is:

```
foreach ($codes as $code) {
echo
    $code['ID'] . '<br/>' .
    $code['Value'] . '<br/>' .
    $code['User'] . '<br/>';
}
```

Could you help and give me a hint what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you have a single-level array, not a multidimensional array.

Comment: Can you explain what you want? What you want to get in final result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array values are not nested so no reason to loop around them. Just access them straight .

```
 $codes = [
   'ID' => 1,
     'Value' => 'NYC125',
     'User' => 1,
     'Uses' => 1,
     'Amount' => 10,
     'End' => 1574467200
    ];



//Simple echo them

echo
    $codes['ID'] . '<br/>' .
    $codes['Value'] . '<br/>' .
    $codes['User'] . '<br/>';
```

Output:

```
1
NYC125
1
```